# wordpress thickbox ignore html tags

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am using Zilla Shortcode, that opens a popup (thickbox) in wordpress. All the DIVs and other CSS stuff works fine, but if doesn't allow me to use any html tags, for example if I write

```
 this is <b>Bold</b>
```

this html is ignored, similarly I have tested, strong, italic etc none of the html tags work in it, I have pent almost 3 hours but cant figure it out, what is making this behavior happened and where should I make that change...

this question is only for wordpress developers as they might have come across this problem..

regards

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question, as it had nothing to do with thickbox or jquery, there was a fix * set to !important :( hence it was ignore anything I was doing even fontawesome were ignored..